# Does this goo effect have a name?

Tags: style-identification

What should I call this goo effect?

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tdyyWV

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is commonly called a "gooey" or "metaball" effect. How to create it depends on the tool that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of a lava lamp. So, maybe lava lamp?

Comment: Hi Pete, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you haven't done so already, I suggest taking the [Tour] to get to know how the site functions. Googling [lava lamp effect](https://www.google.com/search?q=lava+lamp+effect&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZkKqu5evtAhWZDmMBHUwsD9gQ_AUoAXoECBQQAw&biw=1667&bih=860&dpr=2.25) definitely brings up similar visuals.